# Clearing Search text_field_tag In Rendered Form on Submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I am using Rails 5.1 to create a simple search that uses a single text field in a form that gets data from a SQLITE3 DB and returns the data in a table on a new HTML page. The search form is a rendered form which passes the value of the search to the controller

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'search', foo: @foo %>
```

**_search.html.erb**

```
<div>
    <%= form_tag(search_home_index_path, :method => 'get', id: 'search_form') do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id: 'search_field', placeholder: "Search", :required => 'required'%>
        <%= submit_tag("Search", :class => "button", :name => nil) %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**application_record.rb**

```
def self.search(search)
    where("(foo) LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

**home_controller.rb**

```
def search
   if params[:search]
   @foo = Foo.search(params[:search]).order("id ASC")
       else
   @foo = Foo.all.order("id ASC")
   end
end
```

The search is working fine and returning values. However, (and I believe it's because I am rendering the same form on multiple pages), when the search returns, the text_field_tag value retains the search criteria entered on the original page and populates that same value in the text_field_tag on the new page. I have attempted to use JavaScript to clear the text_field_tag by using

```
document.getElementById('search_field').value='';
```

as a function in the

```
<body onload...
```

but it is not working - the text_field_tag retains the value. I have also tried using

```
document.getElementById('search_form').reset();
```

but this ends up sending a blank value in my search variable and returns all the items in the database.

I have seen some references to placing the code for the field value in a Coffee script, but I'm not sure how to implement this (I've been coding Ruby for a grand total of about 2 months now).

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are the one setting this value in your form. You can set it to nil, like so;

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, nil, id: 'search_field', placeholder: "Search", :required => 'required'%>
```

The documentation for the text_field_tag can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag).

Comment: I'm going to now go and beat my head against the wall for thinking this was so much harder than it was...

Comment: Sorry. Thought I did. Thanks.

Comment: @Diane, sorry for the late reaction on your first comment, I hope you did not beat your head against the wall, this happens to the best of us, just don't give up and keep facing with problems :)